# How do I 301 redirect a single page on my Cloudfront/ S3 hosted web page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-301

I use an AWS Cloudfront + S3 solution to host my website.

I redirect all naked domain and vanilla HTTP requests to the prefix https://www.example.com.

The following [S3 Cloudfront Architecture](https://john.soban.ski/how-to-configure-s3-websites-to-use-https-part-1.html) cartoon captures my approach:

[image: Cloudfront + S3 approach]

In addition to the existing logic, I would like to also redirect a single page, namely:

```bash
https://www.example.com/category/coins/
```

to

```bash
https://www.example.com/cat/coins.html
```

I tried to do this via the S3 buckets redirect rules and received a 301 redirect to the bucket address, and not the cloudfront endpoint.

e.g.

```bash
http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cat/coins.html
```

How can I correctly redirect this particular page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS provides [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-redirect-url.html) on how to redirect with CloudFront and that are Viewer Request Functions.

S3 also has [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html) on how to do redirects based on different hosts

- Configure Host name in S3 (S3 -> Properties -> Static website hosting -> Host name). This may rewrite the domain part (I'm not 100% sure)
- Advanced redirection rules allow to replace paths with different keys which should definitely work. There is an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects) on the page that fits the question

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to redirect certain pages:

```json
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "category/data-science"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "john.soban.ski",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "cat/data-science.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "category/coins"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "john.soban.ski",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "cat/coins.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "category/ietf"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "john.soban.ski",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "cat/ietf.html"
        }
    },
    {
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "category/howto"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "HostName": "john.soban.ski",
            "Protocol": "https",
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "cat/howto.html"
        }
    }
]
```